# How do I change the highlighted nav item to have a blue background instead of a blue border-bottom in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I like to change my highlighted nav item to a blue background instead of a blue border underline. See screenshots[image]

my code is here:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
       <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" arial-expand="false">
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
           </button>
            <a href="http://www.aspentech.com/" class="navbar-brand">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo@2x.png">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="login">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li class="active">
                  <a id="loginLink" href="#" class="navbar-text navbar-icon-link">
                  <span class="navbar-profile-icon center-block"></span>Hello, Sijie!</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav subnav-nav">
                <li class="subnav">
                  <span class="navbar-text subnav-link" id="subnav-link-1"><a class="sub" href="index.html">aspenOne Update Center</a></span>
                </li>
                <li class="subnav active">
                  <span class="navbar-text subnav-link" id="subnav-link-2"><a class="sub activated" href="download center.html">aspenOne Download Center</a></span>
                </li>
              </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
     </nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Swathi56/cbe4jdg6/

Comment: use adding `background-color: color_of_your_choice` in `.navbar-collapse .subnav-nav a:hover`, and you'll need to adjust the text color in hover as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
.activated {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #007ABD;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.8s;
    transition: border-color 0.8s;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}
```

And to change color from blue to white add this:

```
.navbar-collapse .navbar-text.subnav-link a.activated {
    color: white;
}
```

To change mobile view, you need use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). For example for sceens less than 600px, media will look like this:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .activated {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #007ABD;
        color: white;
        height: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: border-color 0.8s;
        transition: border-color 0.8s;
        padding-bottom: 16px;
   }

   .navbar-collapse .navbar-text.subnav-link a.activated {
       color: white;
   }
}
```